# Handle class and pointers

Tags: c++

I am reading about handle class idiom in C++ at following link. It is mentioned that

http://bytes.com/topic/c/insights/651599-handle-classes-smart-pointer

> Handle classes usually contain a pointer to the object implementation.
>   The Handle object is used rather than the implemented object. This
>   leaves the implemented object free to change without affecting the
>   Handle object. This is exactly what happens with pointers. The object
>   changes but the address in the pointer does not.

My question is that what does author mean by "This is exactly what happens with pointers. The object
changes but the address in the pointer does not.". Appreciate if explained with example.

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: To be honest, I've found the worst possible examples of C++ code on bytes.com. It was just beyond imagination. I would stay as far away from that site as possible. And handle is simply *a pointer to a pointer*, with all benefits coming from that.

Comment: It is very confusing, but after having a quick look at the article I get the impression those two sentences can just be disregarded.

Comment: A handle is more like an *opaque* pointer, rather than a pointer *to* a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward, maybe the wording is confusing.

The object your pointer points to, can be changed by something else in the program. Its (object's) values can be changed in other places in code. The pointer, however, does not change where it's pointing. That is why

> implemented object free to change without affecting the Handle object.

For example,

```
class Class {
    public: int data;
};

int main() {

    Class myClass;

    Class* myClassPointer = &myClass;

    Class* otherPointer = &myClass;
    otherPointer->data = 10;

    cout << myClassPointer->data << endl;  // value changed, pointer still works

    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the author refers to the fact, that a handle-object can be copied and copied and copied and changes in the original data content of the referred object are accessible through each of the copies - just as it can be done with pointers.

Answer (score 0):

For example, in this code:

```
int a = 5;
int *ap1 = &a;
int *ap2 = ap1;
```

`ap1` and `ap2` are two separate objects which point to a common object.  These pointer objects can be created and destroyed without changing the object that they point to.